# Disabling serial console/kernel messages on Pi B 2 while still being able to write/read to serial port

Tags: serial, node.js, serial-console

I would like to disable the serial console and boot up messages while still being able to write to the port.

I have tried disabling the port in raspi-config. This disables the console and the kernel messages but also removes /dev/ttyAMA0, which my code is writing to.

In my application, I am writing to the port using Node and the SerialPort npm package.

I'm using a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B, and the 2016-05-27 version of Raspian Jessie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit `/boot/cmdline.txt` using `sudo nano /boot/cmdline.txt` or your preferred method, and delete `console=serial0, 115200`.

> If you are using an older version of Raspbian, you might need to delete `console=ttyAMA0, 115200` instead.

After this, reboot and if you do `ls /dev` you should still see `/dev/ttyAMA0`. This worked for my Pi 2 running Raspbian Jessie Lite, which shouldn't be any different from Jessie in this aspect.

> **NOTE:**
>
> Be sure not to delete `console=tty1`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @patrick-cook will work, but if you disabled console in `raspi-config` and rebooted this should already have done the same thing.

Something else may be in play. Possibilities include copying from a Pi3 which disables the default serial port by default through `enable_uart` in `config.txt`. (This is likely to become the default in newer releases.)

In any event you should no longer use `/dev/ttyAMA0` but `/dev/serial0` which is the default serial port on all models.

Comment: I just set up Jessie Lite on a RPi Zero and there's no /dev/serial0 but there is a /dev/serial1 (symlinked to ttyAMA0).